Redis PUB/SUB to scale vertically the websockets for a chat application using Python, FastAPI
I am using Redis to allow the vertical scaling of the websockets, but I am not sure that my two endpoints are using the right logic, because first I started by using the memory locally. but then I decided to change the in-memory of Redis.
Here's the code:
@router.post("/send_message", response_model=MessageResponse)
async def send_message(message: MessageCreate, db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    print("#########")
    # Verify that the sender exists
    sender = db.query(User).filter(User.id == message.sender_id).first()
    if not sender:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=404, detail="Sender not found")

    # Verify that the conversation exists
    conversation = db.query(Conversation).filter(Conversation.id == message.conversation_id).first()
    if not conversation:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=404, detail="Conversation not found")

    # Create the message
    db_message = Message(
        content=message.content,
        sender_id=message.sender_id,
        conversation_id=message.conversation_id,
        content_type=message.content_type,
        status=message.status
    )

    db.add(db_message)
    db.commit()
    print(f"db :{db_message}")
    db.refresh(db_message)

    # Broadcast the message using Redis
    formatted_message = {
        "content": db_message.content,
        "sender_id": db_message.sender_id,
        "conversation_id": db_message.conversation_id,
        "created_at": db_message.created_at.isoformat()
    }
    await broadcast.publish(channel=f"conversation_{message.conversation_id}", message=json.dumps(formatted_message))

    return db_message

@router.websocket("/ws/{conversation_id}/{client_id}")
async def websocket_endpoint(websocket: WebSocket, conversation_id: int, client_id: int, db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    await manager.connect(conversation_id, websocket)
    print("manager connected")
    try:
        async with anyio.create_task_group() as task_group:
            async def receiver() -> None:
                try:
                    while True:
                        data = await websocket.receive_text()
                        message_data = json.loads(data)

                        # Create a MessageCreate instance from the received data
                        message_create = MessageCreate(
                            content=message_data['content'],
                            sender_id=message_data['sender_id'],
                            conversation_id=message_data['conversation_id'],
                            content_type=message_data['content_type'],
                            status=True
                        )

                        await send_message(message_create, db=db)

                        print(f"Publishing to Redis channel conversation_{conversation_id}: {message_create.content}")

                except WebSocketDisconnect:
                    print(f"Client {client_id} disconnected from conversation {conversation_id}")
                    manager.disconnect(conversation_id, websocket)
                task_group.cancel_scope.cancel()

            async def sender() -> None:
                async with broadcast.subscribe(f"conversation_{conversation_id}") as subscriber:
                    async for event in subscriber:
                        await websocket.send_text(event.message)
                        print(f"message: {event.message}")

            task_group.start_soon(receiver)
            task_group.start_soon(sender)
    except WebSocketDisconnect:
        print(f"Client {client_id} disconnected from conversation {conversation_id}")
        manager.disconnect(conversation_id, websocket)


Can you tell me if this is correct or not?
Because when I try to send a message it works, but the print message, is being duplicated, so I assume there is a confusion in my process.
message: {"content": "bonjour", "sender_id": 2, "conversation_id": 1, "created_at": "2024-08-02T12:55:52"}
message: {"content": "bonjour", "sender_id": 2, "conversation_id": 1, "created_at": "2024-08-02T12:55:52"}

